# Where can I find Duel Monster tournaments in the U.S.?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I really want to start getting in matches. I'm still a beginner but I want to practice versing people.

Answer (score 4):

Your Local Gaming/Comic Book Shop likely hosts Yu-Gi-Oh tournaments, along with similar games such as Magic the Gathering, Force of Will, Pokemon, etc.

Without knowing your location, I cannot point you to a specific shop, but there is a store locator available [Here](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/events/locations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Local Card shops would work. Also, if you are planning to go into serious tournaments, look up locations and scheduling of YCS and Regionals